# How to call child(`component`) method from parent?

Tags: ember.js

How to call the child(component) method from parent(router) template?

I would like to know the `ember` recomended correct approach.

here is my try( i am directly calling not works!!)

[Live demo on Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/36b0eade8f27f4d03005dc18ddf45979?openFiles=components.child-omponent.js%2Ctemplates.components.child-omponent.hbs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because ember motto is `Data down, Action up`. Calling an action from child component is not meaningful.

But if it is suitable for your case, use it as `contextual`. Seen as shown [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/56e256954ff88396d2544e20afb4d83c?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.child-omponent.hbs).

Such as:

```
{{#child-omponent as |actionHandler|}}

  <footer>
    <h3 onclick={{action actionHandler }}>Click me to called child components action</h3>
  </footer>

{{/child-omponent}}
```

Comment: so can i keep all my actions in only `routes`?

Comment: if you want, you can. Actually I mostly prefer puting remote data fetching operations on route.